# Is foreach by-definition guaranteed to iterate the subject collection sequentially in Scala?

Tags: scala, collections, foreach, parallel-processing

Is `foreach` by-definition guaranteed to iterate the subject collection (if it defines order) sequentially from the very first to the very last (unless accidentally interrupted) element? Aren't there any compiler optimization switches which can brake it (shuffle the sequence) or plans to make the ordinary `foreach` parallel in future versions?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Foreach is guaranteed to be sequential *for sequential collections* (that is, the normal hierarchy, or for anything transformed by `.seq`).  The parallel part of the collections library (which you get from a standard collection via `.par` or by explicitly using classes from `collection.parallel`) are pretty much guaranteed *not* to evaluate in order.  If you want to be agnostic, you can use the `GenX` set of traits (e.g. `GenSeq`); these provide no guarantees either on execution order or that work will be done in parallel.

Comment: is the answer still valid today?

Comment: @zmerr - It is still valid.  One way in which this property is maintained is through a variety of laws in https://github.com/scala/scala-collection-laws that only pass if `foreach` order is the same as the order for some other operation (e.g. `map` or `flatMap`).  The order of _every_ operation is not tested, but the intent is for sequential collections (in practice, usually everything that is neither a `Set` nor a `Map`, even if it is not a `Seq`) to have all operations use the same order.

Comment: Thanks. Also the implementation uses a while loop which is sequential.

Answer (score 3):

To complement the answer by Rex, `foreach` at `GenTraversableOnce` only guarantees all elements will be iterated through, unless you interrupt it. Traits lower on the hierarchy chain may provide additional guarantees, for example:

- `TraversableOnce` and descendants guarantee that only one element will be iterated through at a time (not guaranteed by `GenTraversableOnce`!).
- `Seq` and descendants guarantee that elements will be traversed on the order they are kept in the collection.

And since you asked about parallel `foreach`...

```
scala> (1 to 10).par foreach println
4
6
1
3
2
7
5
8
9
10
```